# Why doesn’t /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat run daily but will only take effect if I manual trigger it?

Tags: linux, permissions, cron, tomcat, logrotate

I have a `Talend Data Stewardship` application in my server and I would like to rotate the `catalina.out` log file.

Thus, I referring https://dzone.com/articles/how-rotate-tomcat-catalinaout, and create a file call tomcat inside `/etc/logrotate.d`, the content is as follow:

```
/app/talend/801/tds/apache-tomcat/logs/catalina.out {
        copytruncate
        daily
        rotate 700
        compress
        missingok
        size 1M
}
```

On the next day, I saw my log file is still there and not rotate, even the file size is greater than 1M.

However, If I manual trigger by run the following command, then it will rotate:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

May I know is this normal? Can I make it auto rotate daily?

The following is the content on `logrotate.conf`:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

It already include `/etc/logrotate.d` folder, so by right it should read my `tomcat` file?

And the following is my `catalina.out` log file permission:

```
[root@MYUTVLXRORNT01 logs]# ls -lrt catalina.out
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 talenduser talendgroup 2020934 Feb 29 10:06 catalina.out
```

I believe permission 755 should enough?

And the `catalina.out` user and group is `talenduser:talendgroup`, this should be no impact right?

Comment: How are you launching `logrotate`? Is there a cron entry kicking it off, like `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` for example? Check your `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status` file (path may be slightly different depending on distro) and see whether it's running at all or if it's throwing any errors.